# why do we need text inside end tags in XML

Tags: xml

Why do we need text inside end tags in XML? I understand why end tags are present. But having text is redundant since software's can recognize that the current last opened tag is ending when they encounter . By removing text inside the end tags we can save approximately 1/4th of the data consumed by the files. This would results in saving of billions of bytes on global level.

Why can't we use this format

```
<CD>

   <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</>

 </>
```

instead of

```
<CD>

   <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>

 </CD>
```

Comment: There are many text storage formats without a closing tag. For example json and yaml. Choose any.

Comment: It was meant for human readability among other things. Extend your simple example to more complex and large sets where an end tag could be 1000s of lines away from its start tag. Try understanding which tag just ended in that example.

Answer (score 1):

I take the question to be "Why did the designers of XML not allow empty end-tags?  The element type name in the end-tag is redundant; why is it required?"

Yes, it's redundant.  I believe the designers of XML chose to require the element type name in the end-tag because both of the obvious alternatives seemed to have problems of their own.

- Requiring the use of empty end-tags (which would have the form `</>`, following the syntax of SGML) would lead to confusion and errors whenever the start- and end-tag were more than a few lines apart, as Kevin Brown has already pointed out in a comment. (This was certainly my experience in ten years of using SGML, and my recollection is that others reported similar views.)
- Making the element type name optional in the end-tag would make the spec more complex.  Not very much more complex, but perceptibly.

Also, the drawback of the extra bytes just did not (and does not) seem important.  One of the initial design principles for XML (see [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)) was:

> 10. Terseness in XML markup is of minimal importance.

I think you overestimate the cost of the syntactic rule in question.  Using empty end-tags will save 1/4 of the bytes in an XML document in cases where about half the bytes in the document are start- or end-tags and none of the elements have attributes; if any of the elements have attributes, the markup will need to be more than half of the document size.  There are documents like that, but in my experience they are rather rare.  Even in the example data you give, using empty end-tags would not save 1/4 of the bytes (7 out of 44 is 1/6, not 1/4).

If file size were really important, and worth making serious efforts to minimize, then word-processor formats like Word, or rendering formats like PDF, would be much less popular than they are, because a typical human-readable document will be two to ten times larger as a Word file or PDF file than as an XML document.  Are Word and PDF dying out because they make documents so much larger than they would be in a more compact format like XML?

Given the relative unimportance of file size in a world where disk capacity continues to grow faster than anything else in computing, and the obvious utility of the redundancy in helping diagnose syntactic errors or data corruption in an XML data stream, the designers of XML made a choice that seemed reasonable to them at the time.  It does not seem any less reasonable now.

Comment: As an old contributor to SGML I can second this. Unfortunately the world of HTML has progressed into a land of "let's do more with less" for little to no reason. Eliminating a single "/" in things like <br/> <img .../> and even worse making assumptions like "this end tag is not needed because nothing can exist here" ... Their actions while right in their own mind and standards-committee relevance has cause countless man-years of programmatic changes to account for and attempt to process what use to be well-formed, understandable documents.